# Are most functions measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions

Wolfram Mathworld says the following: "In fact, practically any function that can be described is measurable." (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeasurableFunction.html)

How accurate is this?

Note: I don't have much of a background in measure theory at all. I'm just trying to get a very basic understanding of what it means for a function be measurable since that is one of the conditions for a function to be Lebesgue integrable (and for Fubini's theorem to apply).

Comment: 'Most functions' are  not measurable  but 'most functions' we deal with regularly  are measurable in the sense it takes an effort and use of things like axiom of choice to construct even one non-measurable set in the real line.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ok so whenever I'm dealing with double/multiple integrals, the large majority of functions that I'll be integrating will be measurable?

Comment: If you are not doing anything very abstract your functions are measurable. However if you have things like supremum of uncountably many functions (where the supermum cannot be computed explicitly) you have to be careful.

Comment: "that can be described" is a major restriction.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Ok cool. I''m not going to be dealing with anything that abstract. Thanks for your help.